# Azure chat bot fails to authenticate

Tags: python, azure, botframework

I'm trying to create a chat bot using the Bot Framework with Python.  I had this working a few days ago but now I'm getting an error when I test in Azure web chat: `KeyError: 'access_token'`.  This problem is reproducible using sample code from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/releases/download/Templates/echo.zip).

If I remove the app ID and password in config.py and test with the Bot Emulator on localhost then it works fine.  When I change these variables to the correct values and test through `ngrok` it fails with the same exception.

I tried checking the credentials with curl as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python) and it returned this error.

```json
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'd720efc0-d9a3-4c7a-86ab-deed1a27739c' was not found in the directory 'botframework.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: de49aeb5-f200-4427-89f9-973fe2d10701\r\nCorrelation ID: 400d7c55-5854-44a6-a1f1-5a1eb74889da\r\nTimestamp: 2021-04-28 00:00:44Z",
    "error_codes": [
        700016
    ],
    "timestamp": "2021-04-28 00:00:44Z",
    "trace_id": "de49aeb5-f200-4427-89f9-973fe2d10701",
    "correlation_id": "400d7c55-5854-44a6-a1f1-5a1eb74889da",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"
}
```

That sounds like the App ID is wrong, but I verified it by copying the Microsoft App ID from the Azure portal, Bot Channels Registration, configuration page.  I guess it's possible I have the wrong password, but if that's the case I don't know how to change it.

Comment: have you updated ngrok url ?

Comment: You can change the password as per the answer given by @VinothRajendran

Answer (score 1):

1. May be check Messaging endpoint (ngrok url its correct or not)
2. Changing password

Azure -> Bot Channels Registration -> configuration -> Micrsoft Id(Manage) Click Manage link

Client secrets -> New Client secret

Comment: When I click Manage, I get a "404 not found" error.  Self Diagnostics finds no issues